# UE4 - Want my landscape to be unlit BUT catch shadows from objects

Tags: unreal-4

Here is my problem, I have a landscape that was created through photogrametry. I already has strong shadows on it's diffuse texture so I don't want it to be affected by my virtual sun. What I do want though is for objects added in my scene to receive shadows from the landscape, and for the objects to cast shadows onto the landscape. To do that I matched my virtual sun as close as I could with the shadows on the diffuse texture of the landscape.

How do I keep my landscape unlit yet able to receive and cast shadows from and to other objects?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Unreal, but on Unity you can set an object as `unlit`, which will not affect shadows. Is there an option in Unreal, to change a material's shading settings to `unlit` ? It should behave in a similar way, as calculating shadows is a different part than an object's shading.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do that.
But what you can do is to use decals as a shadow which will be pretty hard (and annoying) to do...

OR you can just take the diffuse texture into Photoshop(or whatever you use) and remove the shadow/highlight in 2-4 clicks.

Comment: I ended up doing that but not in Photoshop. I used a much better tool called Agisoft Delighter that use the geometry as helping data for shadow removal.

Comment: @ArthurBlaquart it might be helpful to write up that technique as an answer.